# increment operation in Spring Data Aerospike

Tags: spring-data, aerospike

I'd like to do atomic increment operation on a field in Aerospike.

According to docs [there is such possibility](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/) using `add` operation.

Is there implementation of this operation using [Spring Data Aerospike project](https://github.com/aerospike-community/spring-data-aerospike)?